# Text Editor control for Javascript and CSS

Tags: javascript, text-editor, css, angularjs, wysiwyg

I am looking for a text editor control to embed in an angularJS page to let the end user to be able to edit JavaScript and CSS.
We would need syntax highlight and error reporting at least and code autocomplete functionality would be an additional benefit.